# send/receive data in sockets.io

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, socket.io

I am learning node and sockets and have hit a stumbling block. I have my server running ok, which connects and disconnects users and adds their name to the socket. I have it so that when a user sends a message, anyone else logged in gets it and it appears in a popup alert. What I need is to send more than just the message like the username too and possibly more data. I know its possible with json but how do I include it in the data send and received? I have included the code below. So i want to add the username with the data when sent and received and display it in the popup box, like 'username sent this message.....' It works on the console.log

server.js

```
var http = require('http');
var Static = require('node-static');
var app = http.createServer(handler);
var io = require('socket.io').listen(app);
var port = 8080;

var files = new Static.Server('./public');

function handler (request, response) {
    request.on('end', function() {
        files.serve(request, response);
    }).resume();
}


var numUsers = 0;

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  var addedUser = false;

  socket.on('add user', (username) => {
    if (addedUser) return;

    // we store the username in the socket session for this client
    socket.username = username;
    //addedUser = true;
    ++numUsers;
    // echo globally (all clients) that a person has connected
    //socket.broadcast.emit('user joined', {
    //  username: socket.username,
     // numUsers: numUsers
     console.log(username+' has logged on, now there are '+numUsers+' online');
  });

  //when receive new coors
  socket.on('new_message', function (data) {
    socket.broadcast.emit('new_message', data);
    console.log(socket.username+' just sent '+data);
    });


// when the user disconnects.. perform this
socket.on('disconnect', () => {
       --numUsers;
       console.log(socket.username+' has left, now there are '+numUsers+' online');
});


});
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Example of Getting Current Position</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script> var username = prompt('What\'s your username?'); </script>
<script type="text/javascript">
socket = io.connect('/');
socket.emit('add user', username);

function sendmessage() {
    var new_message = document.getElementById("new_message").value;
    //alert (new_message);
    socket.emit('new_message', new_message);

}

socket.on('new_message', function (data) {
    //socket.broadcast.emit('new_message', data);
    //console.log(data);
    alert(data);
    });

</script>
</head>
<body>
    <button type="button" onclick="sendmessage()">Send message</button><BR><BR>
    <input name="new_message" type="text" id="new_message" value=""><BR>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

Well after a lot of reading up I have done it like so with the following changes:

`index.html`

```
function sendmessage() {
    var new_message = document.getElementById("new_message").value;
    var Details3 = {  
        username: username,  
        message: new_message  
    }; 

socket.emit('new_message', Details3);
```

`server.js`

```
socket.on('new_message', (data) => {
    var New_Details = {  
        username: data.username,  
        message: data.message  
    }; 

    socket.broadcast.emit('update_message', New_Details);
    console.log(data.username + ' just wrote ' + data.message);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

too late to answer but you can do it without json

`index.html`

```
function sendmessage() {
    socket.emit('new_message', username , new_message);
    }
```

`server.js`

```
socket.on('new_message', (username , message) => {
    socket.broadcast.emit('update_message', username , message);
    console.log(username + ' just wrote ' + message);
});
```

I hope it be helpful